# SCEditor: Submit form with Shortcut Ctrl+Enter - How to get instance's parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, sceditor

I have multiple forms with textareas on my site. Each textarea gets the sceditor plugin assigned. Now I am trying to submit a form by providing a shortcut.

First I had a keyup method assigned to each editor instance:

```
$('textarea[name="test01"]').sceditor('instance').keyUp(function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
        console.log(this); // case 1
    }
    // ...
```

And later on I also found the built-in method:

```
$('textarea[name="test01"]').sceditor('instance').addShortcut('ctrl+enter', submitform);
function submitform() {
    console.log(this); // case 2
}
```

My goal is to get the sibling before the sceditor DIV, which is the textarea. From there I can find the submit button. Or I could just go downwards the DOM tree and find the form the textarea / sceditor is nested in.

However, the `console.log(this);` gives for case 1: the HTML of the node, i. e. in the Webdeveloper Console I can see the HTML of the sceditor. For case 2 I receive the sceditor object.

Problem is I cannot access the parent. Also in the [sceditor docs](http://www.sceditor.com/api/sceditor/) I see no way to do this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding the shortcut handler you know which textarea the handler is being added to so you could do:

```
$('textarea[name="test01"]').sceditor('instance').addShortcut('ctrl+enter', function () {
    submitform($('textarea[name="test01"]').get(0).form);
});

function submitform(form) {
    console.log(form.id);
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5jc6f589/

Comment: Outstanding, thanks for the fiddle! Just for the record, I needed to use `form.name` since I have no id assigned. Now I can submit the form using `$('form[name="'+form.name+'"]').submit();`

Comment: Instead of doing `$('#'+form.name).submit();` you should be able to just do `$(form).submit();` since the form variable is the form DOM node.

Answer (score 0):

##### 2023 answer

This can be done via a simple plugin combined with some factory overriding.

###### The plugin

```
sceditor.plugins.shortcut = function ()
{
    let editor;

    this.init = function ()
    {
        editor = this;

        this.addShortcut('ctrl+enter', function () {
            editor.opts.original.form.submit();
        });
    };
};
```

###### The factory override

```
const createFn = sceditor.create;
sceditor.create = (textarea, options) => {
    options.original = textarea;

    createFn(textarea, options);
};
```